# Not able to install socket.io on Windows server 2012

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, windows-server-2012, vcbuild

I am trying to install `Socket.io` on windows server 2012

```
npm install socket.io
```

The error that I am getting is

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [D:\PushNotificationServer\node_modules\socket.io\node
_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [D:\PushNotificationServer\node_modules\socket.io\node
_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
socket.io@0.9.6 node_modules\socket.io
├── policyfile@0.0.4
├── redis@0.6.7
└── socket.io-client@0.9.6 (xmlhttprequest@1.2.2, uglify-js@1.2.5, active-x-obfu
scator@0.0.1, ws@0.4.31)
```

I've installed the framework 2.0 but do I have to buy a licence for visual studio 2005 to install on server? Or is there really a need to install it? Or is there some alternative compiler for server editions?

**The reason behind my question is that the same setup done on windows server 2008 does not throw any error. I did not install anything special on windows server 2008.** 
The problem is with Server 2012 only.
What could be the possible way out?

Comment: that error is caused by `ws` module which requires to be compiled in order to run, what you should do is install the required `.NET 2.0`, and visual studio standard edition. Can't quite recall how i installed `ws` module, but i believe VisualStudio its not mandatory to compile it.

Comment: Can you get any information on this ? I am badly stuck here...

Comment: can you do the following on that machine.. `npm uninstall ws socket.io socket.io-client` and then `npm install ws socket.io socket.io-client -V` then open up a nodejs shell, and do the following `var socketIOClient=require('socket.io-client');` if it returns `undefined` the module loads correctly, entering `socketIOClient` afterwards will return `socket.io-client` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The only solution that I found to this problem:**

----**Instead of compiling the binaries on server, do it on local system.**

Install all the binaries like `Socket.io`, `express` and `connect` on your local system.
Make sure that all required binaries are compiled and loaded into `node_modules` folder.

Simply FTP that folder on your server. (Make sure that `python 2.7` is installed on server)

run

```
node server.js //or yourFile.js
```

and that should work fine.