# Cannot install node-steam for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, steam

I try to install node-steam from ... and got a big error
How can I fix that, is this my fault?
node-steam: https://github.com/seishun/node-steam

```
...
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:101:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\FongZooZ\Desktop\project\test\node_modules\steam\node_modu
les\ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok
...
```

Please help me!

Comment: Reading the error message `failNoPython` can be helpful.
Looks like you need to install python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to Google and find Python 2.6 for your system. (https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6/)
- Download and install the python binaries.
- Assuming you're using Windows, since you didn't tell us your OS, It's installed by default in `C:\python26\python.exe`.
- Now open an empty `CMD` execute `set PYTHON=C:\python26\python.exe`, then run `npm install node-steam` and it should work.

**Note:** If you don't add the PYTHON to your PATH variable, you should type `set PYTHON=C:\python26\python.exe` before each installation that requires Python.

You can find a Linux binaries in their official site too.

Comment: ok, thanks. Installing Python can fix that problem but I received an error like this ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681477/not-able-to-install-socket-io-on-windows-server-2012